# IPFW with MAC ddressing on FreeBSD-11

Tags: ipfw

I have two laptops that I use when I travel. I need them to have access
to my LDAP server. I tried configuring this in my IPFW firewall rules,
but they fail:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="ipfw -q add"
pif="em0"

## Lots of rules - truncated

$cmd allow log tcp from any MAC "0C:54:A5:04:BA:DD" to me 389 in via $pif setup keep-state
$cmd allow log tcp from any MAC "00:1A:A0:89:CA:EA" to me 389 in via $pif setup keep-state
```

This is the error message repeated twice:

ipfw: missing ``to''

If I substitute an IP address and remove the "any MAC "address" it works
fine. I got this example from a web search. Can anyone tell me what I
am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ipfw), the `MAC dst-mac src-mac` is a *rule option* which means it should appear after the `proto from src to dst` part of the rule.

So your rule option is both incomplete and in the wrong place.

Are you attempting to check the MAC address while your laptops are travelling? Because I would have thought that the MAC screening will only be meaningful when the laptops are on the same LAN as the firewall.